# c_mul and regular python multiplication

Tags: python

I was looking at the code sample [here](http://effbot.org/zone/python-hash.htm#integers) and I had a doubt regarding the implementation of the function c_mul. I'm copying the function here for convenience.

```
def c_mul(a, b):
    return eval(hex((long(a) * b) & 0xFFFFFFFFL)[:-1])
```

Would it be the same as `ctypes.c_int32((long(a) * b) & 0xffffffff).value` ?

Comment: Note that the article you're looking at was written back in 2002, 4 years before `ctypes` was introduced. It's so old, `eval('0xFFFFFFFF')` would produce `-1` instead of `4294967295L` on a 32-bit Python build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I certainly think so. The values should be same.